# Should we call send function to actually deploy a contract to the network

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment

I am using the web3.js 1.0 version for creating a contract and communicate to the network. On the web3.eth.Contract object, Should we call the send function, after the deploy function resolve to actually deploy a contract to the network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question is about the **order** of contract deployment and usage, then:

1. Create contract object: 
   `new web3.eth.Contract(jsonInterface[, address][, options])`
2. Deploy contract with options(byte code, arguments): 
   `myContract.deploy(options)`
3. **a)** Use `.call` to simulate what would happen in a transaction, but
   discards all the state changes when it is done.

   **b)** `.send` will send a transaction to the smart contract and execute its method. Note this can alter the smart contract state.

   ```
   myContract.methods.myMethod(123).call({from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe'}, function(error, result){
     ...
   });
   myContract.methods.myMethod(123).send({from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe'}, function(error, transactionHash){
     ...
   });
   ```

---

If you are asking should you use `.send` **right after** contrat deployement:

Best practice is to issue a `.call` first, because it's better to test it for free, before you will execute a transaction and spend some Ether.

Comment: Ok. Thankyou. Sorry for not being clear. My doubt is, when the deploy function is called, whether it actually created the smart contract in the chain, and I could just stop there. Doc says, it resolves to transaction object. So does that mean the contract is in the network, only when I send it?

Comment: To actually deploy sc to blockchain you should use: ‘myContract.deploy().send();’

Comment: So yes, only when you send it.

Comment: @ShonGJoseph If the question is solved, please accept the answer as it is described [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). In your future questions try to be more specific and unambiguous. It will help other people to help you!